# Can "recommend" be followed by an infinitive?

Tags: complementation, infinitive-clauses

In weblio's entry about [recommend](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/recommend) (note: I can't understand the Japanese content), an example is given of "recommend" being followed by an infinitive:

> She recommended me to try this oil for sunburn.

Is this valid English?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is acceptable in all registers. Recommend may take a *that*, gerund, or infinitive complement:

> She recommended that I try this oil for sunburn. ... *with ‘mandative subjunctive’*
>   She recommended {me / my / ∅} trying this oil for sunburn.
>   She recommended me to try this oil for sunburn. ... *with subject ‘raised’ in object case, as the indirect object of* recommend

- ADDED: As FumbleFingers points out, the version with the infinitive and raising may also be understood as a recommendation that *I* (*me*) be the direct object: the person recommended to someone else as the person who should *try this oil*. This ambiguity will ordinarily not arise in context, but it may explain why, as Travis points out, the infinitive complement has been losing ground to the *that* complement: see Travis' link to [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/52090/89555).

An older use which appears to have virtually disappeared is the infinitive with prepositional dative:

> She recommended **to** me to try this oil for sunburn.

Comment: I'm a native speaker (US west coast, living in Australia now), and I'm not sure that I've heard this construction before. Apparently it's much less common now than it was in the past: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/52090/89555 (The thread is quite interesting in its own right.)

Comment: It's probably worth noting that your third form *She recommended me to try X* could also mean *she recommended **to someone else** that I should be the one to try X* (rather than, say, *herself*, or some other "human guinea-pig"). Idiomatically, the very first credible noun after *recommend* is usually the thing being recommended (so for OP's intended sense, I'd probably go for *She recommended this oil for sunburn*, as a "cut-down" version of your first form).

Comment: @Travis A good point - see my addition.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A good point - see my addition.

Comment: I've been put straight several times on ELU (by people who know more than me) when I offer a *reason* why some usage might have gone out of fashion. But [I commented years ago](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52085/recommend-someone/52090#comment97131_52087) that I don't much like the infinitive after *recommend*. And for me at least, that "potential ambiguity" is almost certainly a factor, even if other people might have different reasons.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Linguists have in the last generation become very interested in the question of complementation licensing, and have concluded that there is a Great Complement Shift in progress, replacing infinitives-in-general with gerunds-in-general; but in any particular instance the direction of the shift appears to be pretty much random.

Comment: Yeah - we haven't *quite* reached the point where it would be entirely natural of me to refer to *the **ascending** of the gerund* (as opposed to *ascent* or *ascendancy*), but on the basis of the long-term trend that day may eventually come.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use "She recommended I try this oil for sunburn" or "She recommended this oil for sunburn". The latter is slightly ambiguous!