# Can't use "should" when I write with "recommend"?

Tags: verbs

This question is not like another duplication question.

I'm confused that someone explains the quiz question about example of "recommend".
There are 5 examples of sentence which is used with "recommend".

> 1. I recommend you to visit Gyeongju.
> 2. I recommend you visiting Gyeongju.
> 3. I recommend visiting Gyeongju.
> 4. I recommend (that) you should visit Gyeongju.
> 5. I recommend (that) you visit Gyeongju.

She said only 3 and 5 are correct number. I am very familiar with number 4.

Does she's answer correct? only 3 and 5 are correct? Can't use "should"  when I write with "recommend"?

Comment: Your advisor is a misguided pedant. The very first result from a Google Books search for **"he recommended that I should"** is from *Advanced Writing in English: A Guide for Dutch Authors*. Where it specifically says that *He recommended me to take a taxi* is a "typical mistake", for which the "correct" version is ***He recommended that I ( should ) take a taxi*** (which subjunctive form is correct with or without ***should***). Mind you, most of the 8 "typical mistakes" are constructions that at least *some* native Anglophones do actually use, so I'd say that writer's a bit of a pedant too.

Comment: [Here's](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Advanced_Writing_in_English/-gBH7BQqy_0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22he+recommended+that+i+should+take+a+taxi%22&pg=PA176&printsec=frontcover) the link,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of 'Recommend'.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58421/usage-of-recommend) Also [Can "recommend" be followed by an infinitive?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/32332/) and [Do you recommend (to me)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74420/) and [I recommend or I'm recomending you something](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/139006/), among others.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, that makes sense.  Thanks

Comment: Grammarians should be especially cautious about laying down the law regarding verbs like ***recommend, advise,*** and ***suggest***. Those verbs are typically used in "persuasive" contexts, where a speaker is trying to influence someone else's thoughts or actions. That's often a very "delicate" context, which encourages circumlocutory phrasing, ***as a direct consequence of which*** the syntactic constructions that are commonly used tend to change over time (as people experiment with new ways of "beating around the bush", some of which catch on and endure).

Comment: I hope this question help to someone how do I fix my question instead of  "close "?

Comment: You don't really need to do anything. Personally, I *don't* think you should attempt to "delete" your Q even if you're happy that you've found what you wanted to  know. If enough other users agree with my closevote, this Q will get closed, but I don't think that affects your "reputation" score. Feasibly it *won't* get closed, and maybe someone else will post an answer here that you like, in which case you should "Accept" it. But even if it *does* get closed and has no answers, someone might find this Q before asking a new Q, and follow one of the "duplicate" links to get the answer they seek!

Comment: That's to say - it's generally a good thing to have multiple questions asking essentially the same thing. Hopefully they all get closed except the earliest (or "best") one, but it's easier for a new questioner to find that "original" question if there are several closed questions kinked to it. There's more chance that at least *one* of the closed duplicates will be phrased in a way that matches the title of the new question *before it even gets posted*. If not, it still might be easier  for others here to identify the duplicate *after* it's posted.

Comment: I can see the logic in that "recommend that you should" might be considered tautologous. But true tautologies (where there is genuinely no difference in 
 meaning) are rare, and e.g. in "He recommended that we *should* do it but we didn't" it's natural to use "should" and to emphasise "should", which wouldn't work without.

Comment: @StuartF: I don't see why appending ***...but we didn't*** makes any difference to whether or not ***should*** should be included. Besides normally being completely unnecessary in that exact context, the word is inherently ambiguous - it might be simply a meaningless "function word" occasioned by the *subjunctive* verb ***do** [it]* that follows. OR it could actually mean ***ought to*** (again, redundant, since that meaning is implicit in preceding ***recommend*** anyway).

Comment: NB It's _Is her answer correct?_

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I believe that [an unanswered question with no upvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272420/auto-fix-duplicates-of-questions-deleted-by-the-roomba) is likely to get deleted by the "Roomba", in its weekly sweeping chore, even when the question is closed as a duplicate.  It might take months though. Perhaps we should ask our mod Glorfindel.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: You may be right. But I've just given this question an upvote, which *may* affect things! Obviously this one may as well be closed if no-one posts an answer for a couple of weeks (are we really waiting to see if one of our "once a month" users might be gonna post an answer here?). But I glanced at the answers to some of the questipons I cited as potential dups, and I didn't notice any making the specific point about the relatively "volatile" syntax of "delicate" interactions (between non-equals, or where one party is making an unwelcome observation or offering unwanted advice).